# How to hide controller and action name from start url of my mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

**This Is my route config file:-**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
RouteValueDictionary keyValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
PDCL.API.API _api = new PDCL.API.API();
string cities = _api.GetCities();
string Specialities = _api.GetRouteSpecialization();

routes.MapRoute("SearchClinicListing", "{cityname}/{clinic}/{doctortype}/{clinicname}", new { controller = "Listing", action = "ClinicSearch" }, new RouteValueDictionary { { "cityname", cities } });

routes.MapRoute("AreaListing", "{cityname}/{clinicname}/{areaname}", new { controller = "Listing", action = "AreaSearch" }, new RouteValueDictionary { { "cityname", cities }, { "clinicname", Specialities } });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Listing", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

when I run my project, Default url is **http://localhost:2315/listing/index** 
how can I hide listing/index from that url ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried moving your default route above SearchClinicListing, Let me know if it works

Comment: After moving default route above , my application breaks,it cannot find  all other routes                                                                                                                  Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

In order to have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Listing", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Why don't you have it?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Rename your controller from `ListingController` to `HomeController` since you want it as your starting controller and than when you lunch you project you will have:  `http://localhost:2315`

Comment: After trying this now my url becomes http://localhost:2315/home/index                   Thank You,

Comment: What happens if you just type: http://localhost:2315 and press enter in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the controller and action name from URL is not a good idea. But if you want to do this you should map new route before your Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "MyCustomRoute",
url: "{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Listing", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```